# react-native date without debugger shows Date { NaN }

Tags: javascript, react-native

If you run the below log in browser it works fine. If you run it when `React Native Debugger` is on, it works fine. But when I try to run it without debugger and just use the basic metro bundler, the value returned is `Date {NaN}`. Anyone know the reason why this is happening and how this issue can be solved?

```
console.log('before date', new Date('2004/11/19'))
```

Thank you.

Comment: Try to replace '2004/11/19' to ''2004-11-19''

Comment: that did resolve the issue. thanks for that. but what bothers me is how come it worked all this time and all of a sudden it turned to this error

Comment: I am not sure but share what I know. When debugger is running, react-native will use Chromium engine instead of hermes engine. So, maybe there are differences between engines for handling dates.